# CouchDB 2 and powershell

Tags: powershell, couchdb

I have four CouchDB environments: one dev with four databases, one test with fifty databases, one pre-production and one production, with three databases each.

These environments are **Microsoft Windows 2012 R2 / 2016**; I have to develop a BI by retrieving data from all CouchDB environments and I also have to manage them with ease.

Until now I have managed them with `curl.exe`, but as long as it's about doing a few operations it's all ok.

Then I created a script that uses powershell and .net, in particular Invoke-WebRequest. But even with this it now becomes really difficult to manage the millions of documents that exist for each database in each environment.

I would like to try a module with tools made for this type of work. Can anyone recommend something to me?

Comment: I'm not familiar with CouchDB, but there is a powershell module available. Maybe that will fit your needs. https://matteoguadrini.github.io/PSCouchDB/

Answer (score 1):

I used `curl` on my Arch Linux client machine to always query CouchDB servers. Then I read this article https://dev.to/matteoguadrini/building-cross-platform-application-with-powershell-and-apache-couchdb-539f and I saw that this powershell module also works on Linux. I installed powershell and installed the module. I guarantee you that my life has changed a lot since I use PSCouchDB.

Just think that there are complete commands for each type of action, grouped by topics; for example, if you want to search all the commands concerning the databases, just type this:

```
help *database*
```

or this for documents:

```
help *document*
```

But above all, for a developer like me, the most important thing is that it has debugging. Furthermore its documentation is really exhaustive: https://pscouchdb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

I also recommend it!

Answer (score 0):

I use this powershell module ([PSCouchDB](https://pscouchdb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)) in my production. I installed it on two Linux machines (one Ubuntu and the other Fedora) and also on some Windows clients to call the two servers.

I also used it to make reports by associating it with the `Export-Csv` cmdlet, and then report to Excel.

Very complete and very useful. I recommend it!